# in C#, how can i get the string name from an object

Tags: c#, generics

i have an object that is something like this with a full namespace.

```
MyDomainModel.Model.Application
```

i want to do something like this in a generic function so that it will just display "Application" (without the rest of the namepace

I need to do this in a function that passes in a generic so i tried to do this:

```
typeof(T).ToString()
```

but that didn't work.  any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`typeof(T).Name`  is what you are looking for.

The `typeof` operator returns a `Type` object, which offers [lots of information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) on the type.